# Camel Route not polling file continously for file Delay

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I m using spring boot  with camel . I have the following route configured :

```
from("file://C:/LOGS/HTTPBESample?delay=1000&recursive=true&noop=true").process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange msg) {
                File file = msg.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                LOG.info("Processing file: " + file.getName()+" file size "+file.length());
        rocessing file: " + s);
            }
        });
```

However it runs only once , delay should work like a poller which isnt happening ?

Comment: Will there be new files in the folder, or are you trying to consume same file again?

Comment: is it like if only there are new files ,then only it will work like a scheduler ?

Comment: You have set noop=true, which will also set idempotent=true. This will prevent route from consuming the same file over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

It is still polling, but it is not finding any new files. If you drop a new file in the directory, it will process that one. If you want it to reprocess that same file each poll, you can set the idempotent=false.